# Facebook graph api: post image to feed duplicated capture bug

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im posting message to users feed via Graph Api. I'm using post to this endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed` and sending such parameter: `access_token=my_token&message=message&picture=http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg`

Message gets to the wall, but I have duplicated image's host name: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve it by adding `link` parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=my_token&message=message&picture=http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg&caption=something
```

host name appears in caption add your own caption to solve the problem :)

Comment: custom caption duplicates as well :(